# String Array into arraylist?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have a csv file with unknown amount of columns and row. The only thing I know is that each entry is separated by a comma. Can I use the split method to convert each line of the data into an array and then can I store that Array into an Arraylist. One of the things that concerns me is would I be able to rearrange the Arraylist alphabetically or numerically.

Comment: You can. Try it. If you have specific issues coding that, post them here.

Comment: You could also consider using the String Tokenizer: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: StringTokenizer is obsolete. Use `.split(..)`

Comment: @Bozho, not really, StringTokenizer is still alive and kicking. But I know what you mean. :)

Comment: From the javadocs: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code"

Comment: Do you want an ArrayList<String> (all values) or an ArrayList<String[]> (all rows)?

Comment: I am trying to make a table like in excel and I should be able to change the rows order from row1 to row2 according their column values because each column will hold different numbers and words.

Comment: @Bozho - you are both right. StringTokenizer is not deprecated yet, but it's use is discouraged. I posted a question on this same subject on a different thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227949/how-to-count-duplicates-in-an-array-of-strings/7229816#7229816 would be interested to have your opinions on whether there is ever a case that the use of StringTokenizer can be more performant than split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several questions here so I'll cover each point individually.

> Can I use the split method convert each line of the data into an array

This would work as you expect in the naive case.  However, it doesn't know anything about escaping; so if a comma is embedded within a field (and properly escaped, usually by double-quoting the whole field) the simple split won't do the job here and will chop the field in two.

If you **know** you'll never have to deal with embedded commas, then calling `line.split(",")` is acceptable.  The real solution however is to write a slightly more involved parse method which keeps track of quotes, and possibly backslash escapes etc.

---

> ...into an array than can I store that Array into an Arraylist

You certainly *could* have an `ArrayList<String[]>`, but that doesn't strike me as particularly useful.  A better approach would be to write a simple class for whatever it is the CSV lines are representing, and then create instances of that class when you're parsing each line.  Something like this perhaps:

```
public class Order {
    private final int orderId;
    private final String productName;
    private final int quantity;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    // Plus constructor, getters etc.
}

private Order parseCsvLine(String line) {
   String[] fields = line.split(",");

   // TODO validation of input/error checking
   final int orderId = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
   final String productName = fields[1];
   final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
   final BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(fields[3]);

   return new Order(orderId, productName, quantity, price);
}
```

Then you'd have a list of Orders, which more accurately represents *what* you have in the file (and in memory) than a list of string-arrays.

---

> One of the things that concerns me is would I be able to rearrange the Arraylist according alphabetically or numerically?

Sure - the standard collections support a `sort` method, into which you can pass an instance of `Comparator`.  This takes two instances of the object in the list, and decides which one comes before the other.

So following on from the above example, if you have a `List<Order>` you can pass in whatever comparator you want to sort it, for example:

```
final Comparator<Order> quantityAsc = new Comparator<Order>() {
   public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
      return o2.quantity - o1.quantity; // smaller order comes before bigger one
   }
}

final Comparator<Order> productDesc = new Comparator<Order>() {
   public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
      if (o2.productName == null) {
         return o1.productName == null ? 0 : -1;
      }
      return o2.productName.compareTo(o1.productName);
   }
}

final List<Order> orders = ...; // populated by parsing the CSV

final List<Order> ordersByQuantity = Collections.sort(orders, quantityAsc);
final List<Order> ordersByProductZToA = Collections.sort(orders, productDesc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use:

```
String[] array = input.split("\",\"");
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Note that `Arrays.asList(..)` also returns a `List`, but you can't modify it.
Also note that the above split is on `","`, because CVSs usually look like this:

```
"foo","foo, bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). If you just split on the comma separator, and you happen to have a single cell text containing a comma, but which is enclosed in double quotes to make it clear that it's a single cell, the split method won't work:

```
1, "I'm a single cell, with a comma", 2
3, hello, 4
```

OpenCSV will let you read each line as an array of Strings, handling this problem for you, and you can of course store each array inside a List. You will need a custom comparator to sort your list of lines. Search StackOverflow: the question of how to sort a list comes back twice a day here.

Answer (score 1):

Using split with simple comma is not a fool proof one. If your column data contains a comma, csv would be stored something like a,"b,x",c. In such case split would fail.

I'm not a regex expert maybe someone could write a EMBEDDED_COMMA_DETECTING_REGEX or [GIYF](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+csv+with+embedded+commas).

```
String[] array = input.split(EMBEDDED_COMMA_DETECTING_REGEX);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: +1. I believe that you can split on `","` (added to my answer), as CSVs will wrap all values in quotes if they allow commas in the entries